# Is Testaments material used a lot in Handmaid's Tale?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-handmaids-tale, margaret-atwood

I recently read the Handmaid's Tale. I roughly had an idea about how much of the book is used in the series and where the series end in terms of books. [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187367/was-all-the-source-material-used-up-in-the-handmaids-tale-season-1) also helped me in my decision. So I assumed it is not a bad idea to watch the first season without reading Testaments.

Yet, in the very first episode, I learned that

> Offred's real name is June,

which is not covered in the Handmaid's Tale.

My question is, how much material from the Testaments is used in the first two seasons of the series? Is Testaments material frequently used or the information above is just a fluke?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Testaments - "*Atwood wrote The Testaments in coordination with the ongoing The Handmaid's Tale television series, letting the producers know where she was taking the sequel and affirming certain characters' storylines are not impacted by how they appear in The Testaments, since the setting of the television series is several years away from directly portraying events in this novel. Bruce Miller, producer of the television series, has acknowledged the new novel's storyline will be taken into account as the series continues*

Comment: @Valorum From this quote, I understand that the producers will not be taking too much liberty as it might disrupt the portrayal in the second book. But it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Hence why I didn't post it as an answer....

Comment: I couldn't get the relevance as well.

Comment: The relevance is that they were talking about the sequel novel while they were making the TV series. So there was clearly *some* crossover from one to the other.

Comment: While Offred's name is never confirmed in the original book, "June" was always the only possibility for which there was an evidence.

Comment: @Buzz Was there an evidence towards xxx in the original book? Where was the evidence? Shall I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @C.Koca It's probably better as a separate question, where "June" comes from.